# Need help using Advanced Custom Fields with Flexslider 2

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, flexslider

I am trying to produce a basic slider in Wordpress using ACF & Flexslider 2. I want to show text on the left & an image on the right, like the arrangement I've created in the attached screenshot.

I want the slider to rotate out 2-3 more artist bios in this exact same format with the blue background acting as the slider container. I successfully created custom fields using an ACF repeater, with subfields for the name, title, bio text, and image. The problem I'm having is that after I create the repeater, flexslider doesn't show up at all and instead I can see all of my repeater fields at once, like this:
[theg8.com/about-the-art/](https://theg8.com/about-the-art/)

Here is the PHP in my template file:

```
<li class="mason__grid-col col__full artist-highlight-section">
 <?php if( have_rows('artist_slider') ): ?>
  <div class="col-12 artist-info">
   <?php while( have_rows('artist_slider') ): the_row(); ?>
    <div class="artist-info-left col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
      <h2><?php the_sub_field('artist_name'); ?>
      </h2>
      <h3><?php the_sub_field('artist_title'); ?></h3>
      <p><?php the_sub_field('artist_bio'); ?></p>
     </div>
    <div class="artist-image-right col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
     <figure>
       <?php
         $image = get_sub_field('artist_image');
         $imageurl = $image['sizes']['slider'];
         ?>
       <li class="lazy"><img src="<?php echo $imageurl; ?>"></li>
      </figure>
     </div>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
   </div><!-- ends col-12 -->
 <?php endif; ?>
</li>
```

Anyone able to help?

[Screenshot of correct styling](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbX2d.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding all of the slider information into just one slide.

FlexSlider uses a separate `<li>` for each slide, but you have your ACF loop *inside* your `<li>`... you need to move it outside and created a new `<li>` for each slide you want.

Assuming this this html works for your slider before you added the ACF fields, your code should look like this (See setps 1 and 2 in the comments, and don't forget to change your ending tags to match!):

```
<?php  /* 1. loop through the ACF rows first... */ ?>

<?php if( have_rows('artist_slider') ): ?>
  <?php while( have_rows('artist_slider') ): the_row(); ?>

   <?php  /* 2. then for each 'artist_slider' row, 
                create a new <li> and fill it with the details from the ACF row */ ?>

   <li class="mason__grid-col col__full artist-highlight-section">
      <div class="col-12 artist-info">
          <div class="artist-info-left col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
            <h2><?php the_sub_field('artist_name'); ?></h2>
            <h3><?php the_sub_field('artist_title'); ?></h3>
            <p><?php the_sub_field('artist_bio'); ?></p>
          </div>
          <div class="artist-image-right col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-sm-12">
           <figure>
             <?php
               $image = get_sub_field('artist_image');
               $imageurl = $image['sizes']['slider'];
               ?>
             <li class="lazy"><img src="<?php echo $imageurl; ?>"></li>
           </figure>
         </div>
       </div><!-- ends col-12 -->
    </li>
  <?php endwhile; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Oh, thank you! Now that I have the correct ACF loop structure with flexslider, I'm able to see that the slider works (I can see the navigation buttons in the bottom right); however, I can't see any of the ACF fields as the slide content. It pops up and looks correct for a split second and then disappears. I don't see anything in the console that points to the problem. Do you have time to take another look? Thank you!

Comment: @ceteed Glad you got that working! If my answer helped, you should consider accepting it :) The new problem sounds more like Flexslider or the slide structure than with the ACF content. That would be a new post here - each question should be about one single issue. A few things to try first: Did you get it working with standard HTML before adding the ACF content? I'd suggest stripping it back to a simpler working version, then bit by bit add back your classes, bootstrap, ACF fields etc. to narrow down the problem. This will help you get better answers if you do post again :)